# BFS Algorithm in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, tree, breadth-first-search

I am new to Trees and BFS/DFS as well as programming and I decided to play around to learn how to traverse trees.

I did not want to use the `shift()` JavaScript function.

The constructors and code are below.  Since I am new, I would like to know how I may improve my code.  If the method implemented is inefficient, and if so, how may I make it more efficient.

I realize I could possibly combine the `traverse()` and `secondTrav()` function in to one, by including some conditionals, so I will be trying to fix this as well.

Node constructor:

```
function Node(data){
     this.data = data;
     this.left = null;
     this.right = null;
}
```

Tree constructor:

```
function Tree(){
      this.root = null;
}
```

Pushes Nodes in to Tree (Binary):

```
Tree.prototype.push = function(val){

     var root = this.root;

     if(root === null){
       this.root = new Node(val);
       return;
     }

     var currentNode = root;
     var newNode = new Node(val);


     while(currentNode !== null){
       if(val < currentNode.data){
         if(currentNode.left === null){
           currentNode.left = newNode;
           break;
         }else{
           currentNode = currentNode.left;

         }
       }else{
         if(currentNode.right === null){
           currentNode.right = newNode;
           break;
         }else{
           currentNode = currentNode.right; 
         }
       }
     }
   }
```

Function to implement BFS, returns Node values as an Array:

Can `traverse()` and `secondTrav()` be combined?

```
function bfs(tr){

    var stackLeft=[];
    var stackRight=[];
    var order = [];
    var currentNode1 = tr.root;

    stackLeft.push(currentNode1);
    traverse(stackLeft);


    function traverse(stackLeft){
      stackRight=[];
      for(i=0; i<=stackLeft.length-1; i++){
        order.push(stackLeft[i].data)

        if(stackLeft[i].left !== null){
          stackRight.push(stackLeft[i].left);
        }
        if(stackLeft[i].right !== null){
          stackRight.push(stackLeft[i].right);
        }
      }
      if(stackRight.length === 0 && stackLeft.length === 0){
        return order
      }else{
      secondTrav(stackRight);
      }
    }

    function secondTrav(stackRight){
      stackLeft=[];
      for(i=0; i<=stackRight.length-1; i++){
        order.push(stackRight[i].data)
        if(stackRight[i].left !== null){
          stackLeft.push(stackRight[i].left);
        }
        if(stackRight[i].right !== null){
      stackLeft.push(stackRight[i].right);
        }
      }
      traverse(stackLeft);
    }
    console.log(order);
}
```

The above code works for the following implementation:

```
var newTree = new Tree();

newTree.push(100);
newTree.push(90);
newTree.push(110);
newTree.push(105);
newTree.push(95);
newTree.push(92);
newTree.push(97);
newTree.push(107);
newTree.push(102);

bfs(newTree);
```

Comment: (Welcome to CR!) If it is a *search*: what is it expected to find? I prefer traversals with no "early out"/nothing to find, well, *traversal*. You have description all around your code - how about putting some in? `Since I am new, I would like to know how I may improve` if lucky, you keep like that (inquisitive - *new does* wear off).

Comment: `combine the traverse() and secondTrav() function` for a first step, put into words what each does, pinpointing differences.

Comment: Hi greybeard!  Thanks for the suggestions!  I will try to edit later and add some comments within code